# undefined method `is_current' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x38622a8> in ruby on rails update data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I'm trying to update some data in database but I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `is_current' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x38622a8>
```

My controller:

```
@user = User.where("user_id = #{user_id} and is_current = 1") 

if @user.nil?
  puts"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
else 
  @user.is_current = 0
  @user.to = Time.now
  @user.save
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User.where returns an array.  You need to say .first afterwards.  Additionally do not use a string in where with out escaping your arguments.  Your query is not secure and is open to SQL injection.

```
@user = User.where(user_id: user_id, is_current: 1).first
```

Comment: and for completeness' sake, you can use prepared statements if you must use a string for some reason: `User.where('user_id = ? and is_current = 1', user_id)`

Answer (score 1):

try to write query in model, it's good practice, so you can do

```
@user = User.where("user_id = #{user_id} and is_current = 1")
```

replace with

```
@user = User.user_is_current(user_id,1) # two argument 1) user_id and 2) is_current value
```

in your model

```
def user_is_current(user_id,is_current)
  where(user_id: user_id, is_current: is_current)
end
```

it will give data in array so you can write

```
 @user = User.user_is_current(user_id,1).first
```